# Negation of convergence symbol?

Tags: math-mode, symbols

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to look up a math symbol?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol)

How do I express the opposite of convergence?

I would type `$x\rightarrow 0$` to say that x converges to 0, but how can I make the crossed out `\rightarrow` appear

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-math-symbol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `amssymb` package offers `\nrightarrow`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}
\[
  a_n \nrightarrow 0.
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

A similar symbol is also available using the same command with the `MnSymbol` and `mathabx` packages (`mathabx` changes the shape of many other symbols).

Whenever you need a symbol, you have two initial resources:

1. You can look things up in the [Comprehensive LaTeX symbols list](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/comprehensive).
2. You can try [Detexify](http://detexify.kirelabs.org/classify.html), which allows you to draw the symbol and tries to recognize your drawing.

Answer (score 6):

You could prefix `\not` to whatever symbol (e.g., `\to`) you select for "convergence", as in `$x\not\to 0$`. (`\to` is a synonym for `\rightarrow`...)